# Recursion - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

So I'm writing a code as an exercise for recursion. Its purpose is to sort an array of integers in an ascending order by recursively replacing the last element of the array with the largest one. I keep getting segmentation fault error and can't find out where the problem is. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void selection_sort(int array[], int length);

int main (void)
{
    int array[N];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a series of integrs: ");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    selection_sort(array, N);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void selection_sort(int array[], int length)
{
    int max = array[0];
    int temp;
    int i;
    int maxPlace;

    if (length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < length; i ++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max)
        {
            max = array[i];
            maxPlace = i;
        }
    }
    temp = array[length - 1];
    array[length - 1] = max;
    array[maxPlace] = temp;

    selection_sort(array, length - 1);
}
```

Comment: `maxPlace` isn't assigned unless you ever enter the conditional `if (array[i] > max)`, though it is used unconditionally in the line `array[maxPlace] = temp`. Try setting maxPlace to 0 on declaration and see if that helps.

Comment: A segmentation fault means that you can _either_ run in a debugger, and it will show you precisely where the fault occurs, and the value of every variable and memory location at that point, _or_ run it with a reasonable (non-zero) core size limit, and load the resulting core file in your debugger for roughly the same result. Do one of those, and if you can't see the problem, come back with the stack trace, line, values etc.

Comment: @GovindParmar This indeed appeared to be the problem. Initialized to 0 and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedOuf In fact this declaration         int max = array[0]; is redundant, It is enough to declare int maxPlace = 0;

Comment: I like this question because it has only one glaring bug, and because it caused this awesome answer to happen.

Comment: In the future try running your program inside `gdb` and when the segfault happens run `bt` and it will tell you the exact line it crashed on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `maxPlace` might be uninitialized. And because you're reading input incorrectly such that you'll always get `N` elements even if the user only put in 1.

---

It's illustrative to show how I tracked this down. Normally I'd track down a segfault using [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) which would tell me the offending line, but that's currently broken on OS X. So here's the old fashioned way with prints and deduction.

First, the `-fsanitize=address` compiler flag will cause a runtime failure if you walk off the end of allocated memory, such as using an uninitialized variable. This can usually catch memory errors as soon as they happen rather than far down the road. It will also tell you what function it happened in.

```
$ make
cc -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`   -c -o test.o test.c
cc `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -lssl -lcrypto -fsanitize=address  test.o   -o test

$ ./test
Enter a series of integrs: 5
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==80879==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7ffee6679358 (pc 0x0001095a7cac bp 0x7ffee6659330 sp 0x7ffee66592b0 T0)
    #0 0x1095a7cab in selection_sort (/Users/schwern/tmp/./test+0x100001cab)
    #1 0x1095a78db in main (/Users/schwern/tmp/./test+0x1000018db)
    #2 0x7fff73819114 in start (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x1114)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV (/Users/schwern/tmp/./test+0x100001cab) in selection_sort
==80879==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

Now I know it's in `selection_sort()`. I can start adding debugging print statements to narrow it down. That `for` loop is suspect, maybe you're walking off the array, so I started with that. I'll also want to know if you recurse, so I've put a print on that.

```
puts("Entering loop");
for (i = 1; i < length; i ++)
{
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    if (array[i] > max)
    {
        max = array[i];
        maxPlace = i;
    }
    puts("Loop next");
}
puts("Leaving loop");

temp = array[length - 1];
array[length - 1] = max;
array[maxPlace] = temp;

puts("Recursing");
selection_sort(array, length - 1);
```

And try that...

```
$ ./test
Enter a series of integrs: 5
Entering loop
i: 1
Loop next
i: 2
Loop next
i: 3
Loop next
i: 4
Loop next
i: 5
Loop next
i: 6
Loop next
i: 7
Loop next
i: 8
Loop next
i: 9
Loop next
Leaving loop
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
```

Nope, you're not walking off the array. But you're also not recursing. So it has to be in just the few lines of code after the loop. Ok, mark those up. Nothing fancy, numbers are fine when the scope is this small.

```
puts("1");
temp = array[length - 1];
puts("2");
array[length - 1] = max;
puts("3");
array[maxPlace] = temp;
```

Run that...

```
$ ./test
Enter a series of integrs: 5
Entering loop
i: 1
Loop next
i: 2
Loop next
i: 3
Loop next
i: 4
Loop next
i: 5
Loop next
i: 6
Loop next
i: 7
Loop next
i: 8
Loop next
i: 9
Loop next
Leaving loop
1
2
3
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
```

Now I know it's after `3` and before `recursing`. That means it's `array[maxPlace] = temp;`. Ok, what's in `maxPlace`?

```
puts("1");
temp = array[length - 1];
puts("2");
array[length - 1] = max;
printf("maxPlace: %d\n", maxPlace);
array[maxPlace] = temp;
```

Run that...

```
$ ./test
Enter a series of integrs: 5
Entering loop
i: 1
Loop next
i: 2
Loop next
i: 3
Loop next
i: 4
Loop next
i: 5
Loop next
i: 6
Loop next
i: 7
Loop next
i: 8
Loop next
i: 9
Loop next
Leaving loop
1
2
maxPlace: 32766
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
```

`maxPlace` being 32766 means it probably contains garbage. Now that I know what variable is the problem I can look at how it's declared, initialized, and set to discover there's a case where it will never be initialized: if the list is sorted in descending order.

---

But I only put in one number, 5! Shouldn't `if (length < 2)` have caught that? No, because you're always iterating over `N` elements no matter how much input you read.

```
printf("Enter a series of integrs: ");
for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

If I put in `5` and then hit `ctrl-d` to end input, `scanf` will only set `array[0] = 5`. But the loop will continue running for 1 to 9. `scanf` will fail because `stdin` is closed. The rest of the array will be uninitialized.

And you're sorting `N` elements, not the number read. So you'll always sort 10 elements whether they're initialized or not.

You're getting lucky that they happen to be 0.

```
$ ./test
Enter a series of integrs: 5
In sorted order: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
```

Instead, you should be reading until `N` or until `scanf` fails, whichever comes first. This will also protect you from garbage input. And also only sort and print up to the number of integers read, not the maximum capacity of the array.

```
int main (void)
{
    int array[N];
    int num_ints;

    printf("Enter a series of integrs: ");
    for(num_ints = 0; num_ints < N; num_ints++)
    {
        if( scanf("%d", &array[num_ints]) < 1 ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    selection_sort(array, num_ints);

    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < num_ints; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```